# Why does git clone fail to stat files on Linux Mint?

Tags: python, git

I try to download blackwidow.git and i set it up like katoolin:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/1N3/BlackWidow.git && cp BlackWidow/BlackWidow.py /usr/bin/BlackWidow
```

But I get an error message:

```
cp: cannot stat 'BlackWidow/BlackWidow.py': No such file or directory
```

What is this error caused by (**note:** both katoolin and blackwidow are written in python)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in that repo, there's no BlackWidow.py script at its root. Just checked in https://github.com/1N3/BlackWidow. Try **cp BlackWidow/blackwidow /usr/bin/blackwidow** instead

Comment: I addition you are going to need root permissions to write to `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: Linux file systems are typically case sensitive.